# Dygraph synchronization changes Y-scales

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

This small zip has everything to display a 7 channel dygraph.
Syncronization works. The only problem is that zooming causes all other
Y-scales to change.
Any suggestion how to solve it ?

http://www.dulob.com/dygraph_sync_example_7_Channels.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `zoom` option to the synchronizer, see [example here](http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html)

```
const sync = Dygraph.synchronize(graphs, {
    zoom: false
});
```